# Print using only black on Canon MP280 and 12.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am using 12.04 and have a Canon PIXMA MP288. As the colour cartridges are so expensive I want to print only using the black cartridge, but there seems to be no way to do this and the answers provided here so far do not work. 
I am sure this was possible using windows. Is it just a driver problem?

Answer (score 2):

To permanently change printing mode to "black only" do this:

On an internet browser go this webserver:

localhost:631

Then go to Printers (top right of the screen).
On "queue name" click on the printer.
Go to 'Administration' and select 'Modify Printer'.
Choose the first 'usb' option and click continue.
Next screen continue again.
On the next screen select this printer in Model:

Canon PIXMA MP280 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9

And then for last click on 'Modify Printer'.

Exit the browser and change your printer settings.

On Lubuntu 13.04
Start Menu -> System tools -> Printers
Choose properties on the MP280.

In the Printer Options screen.
Choose:
Color Mode: Greyscale
Ink type: Black
Ink set: Black

Click Apply and then OK.

Finally DONE!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out! Here is how I did it:

I was about to print something, but I paused it and saw it said 'Settings' next to the pause button. This is how I went from there:

1. Click on 'settings' and you will see thee tabs: General, Supply Levels and Utility. Click on Utility.
2. Once on the 'Utility' tab click 'Open Printer Utility' and it will pop up a new page.
3. Click on the 'Ink cartridege settings' from the scroll down menu  . It will then let you decide if you want to use color only, black ink only, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your printer and select 'Colour'. Then select 'Black'. Print and out it comes in black!

Comment: There is no "printer" options available unless I am about to print. Then only grayscale is available which as you know uses the colour cartridge. Your answer seems to be directed to windows users.

Comment: If I said "go to your **printer**" how could it be directed to Windows? I said printer, not Windows/Ubuntu.

Comment: In Windows it is simple to select black only from printer options. There is no such facility in Ubuntu.The printer "tool" button cycles through 10 codes but there is no info (including in that which came with the printer) that tells you what these codes mean. Does 1 of them force the printer to use black only? Advice: when someone has bothered to jump all the necessary hurdles to ask a vaild question it is because after some effort they still do not know what to do. Please don't make everyone you answer sound like a moron, by supplying answers that do not clearly express a full solution.

Comment: I meant the Printer Options on your **Printer**. Not Ubuntu. Please understand that.